# Avoiding syntax error for 'as' statement in python

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error from python for the 'as' statement. I don't know for sure but I suspect my web server has out of date python.

```
x@y.com [~/www/dmi-tcat/helpers]# python urlexpand.py
  File "urlexpand.py", line 70
    except HTTPError as e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
x@y.com [~/www/dmi-tcat/helpers]#
```

Can anyone confirm this and is there a way to write the same piece of code without the as statement? My host doesn't want to upgrade python at the minute.

Comment: What do you get for `python --version`?

Comment: The solution is not using ancient python versions. If your host refuses to upgrade from 2.5 which is EXTREMELY old and outdated it is a bad company which does not deserve paying customers. By using Python 2.5 you lose tons of other useful features, too.

Comment: Golly, you've got a bee under your bonnet haven't you? In the real world, sometimes we have to work with old software, even when we'd like to update.

Comment: Old software is one thing. An EIGHT year old version of a programming language is a different thing. That's barely acceptable. Especially since it doesn't seem to be some enterprisey environment (and even those distributions usually have at least python 2.6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The older python syntax is

```
try:
    ...
except HTTPError, e:
    ...
```

If you want to catch multiple error types, pass a tuple:

```
try:
    ...
except (AttributeError, TypeError), e:
    ...
```